# How to run a task periodically in all UIViews (Swift language)?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I've been searching for a solution and I'm kinda confused. I need to run a task periodically in all my UIViewControllers. Basically I want to check the content of my database say every 10 seconds to see if a variable has changed from 0 to 1. I read about NSTimer and Dispatch_time but I wasn't sure if they continue to run if I segue from one view to anther. How can I achieve this?

The second part of my question is how can I pass this task to the background thread? Say if the user locks his/her phone I want the app to still check the database UNTIL the variable changes from 0 to 1.

I'm new to app programming and iOS architecture. If there is anything that I can read to help me with this task please suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered running a `Thread`?

Surely people will say beginners should never touch threads as being not careful could lead to very unpredictable bugs, etc.
The thing is sometimes you really have to make use of them, and your need is suited for threads.

Threads run in background of your program, separated from the rest of your code and the rest of the threads. That means threads don't wait for anything else, only if u ask them to.

Learn more about `Threads` in Swift here: https://thatthinginswift.com/background-threads/

Comment: As to OPs need to be able to know about this change from virtually any point in his app, it may also be worthwhile to read about Singletons and delegates/notifications.

Comment: Not really. He already stated he needs to run a task periodically like every 10 secs. Doing so would not allow his task check code to interfere *too much* with any other functionalities. So threads remain the best shot

Comment: Yep, you are right. What I meant is that having a singleton to manage the thread and inform all interested parties about the change would be a good idea. No need to actively ask if the change has happened when you can be informed about it ;)

Comment: Do you guys think this would be the right way of doing this or should I use Apple notification?

Comment: @Losiowaty I agree on that one

Comment: Thanks guys! I decided to create a thread to do this and it works well so far.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the right approach for mobile application, to polling for change of the database entries. Somewhere from you code this database entries are being updated. You can use post `NSNotification` using `NSNotificationCenter` from where your database entries are updated. All views who registered for listening that notification will be notified of this changes.

```
//for listening for notification
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@SELECTOR(methodWhichWillBeInvoked) name:@"yourname" object:nil];


//for posting notification
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotifcationName:@"yourname" object:nil];
```

Whenever you are sure that, you don't need to observe for the NSNotification, you should unsubscribe in following manner.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

for posting NSNotification [check here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/)

observing for NSNotification [check here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNotificationCenter/postNotificationName:object:userInfo:)

for unsubscribing [check here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/)

Another thing, ios app can run in background, you may get suggested to play silent audio to keep you app running, but you app will be appstore rejected upon such behaviour.

hope they help you.

Comment: Please add information about unsubscribeing from receiving notifications and when to do it, as failing to do so may lead to unexpected behaviour and memory leaks.

Comment: I read somewhere that I have to subscribe to Apple notification center for this. Is that true?

Comment: information added @Losiowaty, Please let me know what is Apple notification center ? please add some reference (to ali m)

Comment: Thanks, though pity that its only a link. I think that OP may be confusing `NSNotifications` with push notifications.